# If you have an object pushing or pulling another object, can you convert that force into electricity without either object moving?

Tags: classical-mechanics, electricity

If you have an object pushing or pulling another object, is it possible to convert that force into electricity without either object moving?

**If so, what possible methods could be used for harvesting the pushing/pulling force, and using it to generate electric current?**

If the method of generating electricity results in the pushing/pulling force being reduced (e.g. in order to satisfy thermodynamics), that's OK as long as both objects remain stationary and at least some electrical current is generated.

For example, object **`A`** might be firmly anchored to the floor, object **`B`** is tethered to object **`A`**, and object **`B`** pulls on object **`A`** via a general input force of some kind (e.g. people pulling on it, or whatever).

Either "pushing" or "pulling" forces could be used, since there are essentially interchangeable using levers etc.

Answer (score 4):

In order to generate electricity work must be done. If you push or pull on an object and it does not move you are not doing any work since work is force times the  distance the object moves  in the direction of the force.

If you’ve been following the comments you may have learned that physical effort does not necessarily produce work. If you push or pull an object and it DOES move you’ve done work as defined by physics. If it doesn’t move you haven’t done work as defined by  physics. You physical effort  will expend calories causing you to breath more rapidly and sweat transferring more heat from your body  and increase your heart rate making it work harder (internal work of your body) but you are not doing external work defined by physics.

Hope this helps

Comment: This was expanded upon in another answer. If you simultaneously push and pull an object with equal and opposing forces, the object _technically_ "moves" in opposing vectors, which cancel each other out. In other words, if you push and pull the object, the object doesn't move, but work is still done.

Comment: @CompellingArgument I found the question confusing it sounded like nothing moves. Of course if there is some time of reciprocating motion work is done.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the confusion. That's why I asked the question in the first place, since I was confused around the same issue. In my example, with objects tethered and anchored, there are opposing pulling forces at play, but no movement. So indeed, nothing moves in the example, and yet it seems work is still done. Capturing that work is where things get tricky/interesting IMO. **EDIT:** Perhaps there is movement if a tethering chain is made of metal, which is malleable and very slightly stretches? Perhaps that is where the heat output is generated.

Comment: @Compelling Argument If nothing moves what makes you think “and yet it seems work is still done “? Don’t confuse physical effort with physics work.

Comment: Physical effort = energy which must be conserved. If the object doesn't move, the energy must manifest as some other form of output, other than movement. Although it just occurred to me that you said _"In order to generate electricity work must be done."_ Whereas I guess I'm talking about generating heat now ... which isn't exactly what I asked for originally, but it's a step in the right direction I suppose.

Comment: @Compelling Argument Sure energy is conserved. But the calories you burn is not doing physics work (force times distance). You breathe more rapidly expelling more warm carbon dioxide, you may sweat losing heat by evaporation, your heart does more  work by beating  faster, etc. But you aren’t doing physics work.

Comment: @CompellingArgument It is unfortunately not correct that "physical effort =energy". Not necessarily, at least. When a table is standing on the floor, the floor applies a force to hold up the table. This "effort" expends no energy. No energy loss og Generation of any kind. The floor could do this forever. This seems to be similar to your situation. Now, certain "machines" do spend energy in order to produce a force. Such as a rocket burning fuel or a human body spending the chemical energy from nutrients in food. But these usually require an energy input.

Comment: @CompellingArgument You're thinking about people being involved in pulling the rope too much I think.  Imagine that instead of a person pulling on object B, it's pulled by a weight on a pulley, or by a anchoring object B to the ceiling.  In that cases, there are net _forces_ acting on each system; but there's no net movement, and the anchors aren't expending any energy to stay in place.  They are held in place by forces, not energy expenditure.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way that gives you *almost* what you want.

There are ceramic materials called *piezoelectrics* which, when sliced into thin slabs and squeezed, produce a small amount of voltage (and almost zero current). If you stacked together a very large array of these "tiles", connected them together in parallel and squeezed them, you could produce several volts and if you are lucky one thousandth of an amp of current for a thousandth of a second or so: a tiny amount of useful power for a huge investment of time and effort.

Piezoelectric discs like this are handy for making microphones and the little beepers that tell you when your microwave is finished heating up your corn dogs, but they are impractical as power generators.

Note that these devices do obey the rule cited by Bob D above: when you squeeze a piezoelectric disc, the **force** you apply (which is significant) must move through a **distance** (which, because the disc is stiff, will be extremely small) in order to perform **work** on the disc. The disc then transforms that work into a voltage (which is significant) and a current (which will be extremely small).

Comment: Niels, I agree with your answer (I up voted it). The problem the OP is having, as well as the Warrior and Compelling Argument, is thinking that physical effort necessarily equals work, even when the effort does not result in movement of the object. This is not the first time this has come up. Bob

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is so strict so as to not allow a single atom to move, electric current cannot happen (electric current is flowing electrons). So the short answer to this question is "no".

The longer answer: it depends on how strict your "no movement" requirement is (and what you consider to be unacceptable movement).

For example, consider a waterwheel mounted to a dynamo, and anchored in a river. Say you hook up an empty rechargable battery to the dynamo and come back a while later. When you come back, the battery is charged. And the waterwheel, dynamo, and river are where you left them.

- In a "big picture" view, there was no movement.
- In a "detail oriented" view, the waterwheel and dynamo's rotor turned (which is movement), and numerous water molecules flowed and collided with the waterwheel paddles, and flowed downstream from the waterwheel (which also is movement).